# Update/redo Database fetch PHP after function

Tags: php, mysql

I got a page that displays a value from database that i got by fetch.

Lets say clicking a button triggers a function that changes the database value (increases it by 1).

The value is changed in the database, but the page still shows the old number.

Is there any way to update this number without refreshing the page?

Comment: what have you tried before coming to SO?

Comment: How are you changing the value in the database without refreshing the page? If you’re already using Ajax use it to get the new value too. Besides, if you already know what the new value will be, you could just change the value on the page in js without refetching it from your db

Comment: ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs for about 2 hours now

Comment: @itcher $database->query("UPDATE users SET value=value+1 WHERE name='$_SESSION[username]'");

Comment: That looks like php to me how’re you getting there from the client side? Maybe post your code so that we could know where you’re up to and what you’ve tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way of updating using JavaScript.

You can use **AJAX** to connect to the server without reloading the page. For an introduction in AJAX, see [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) for the JavaScript part and the [official PHP documentation](http://php.net/docs.php) for the PHP part. You can also have a look at [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) if you want, but don't use it as your only source of learning.

Note that you have to write JavaScript and PHP code to get it working.

Comment: never recommend w3schools - its riddled with bad practices

Comment: What is bad about w3schools? Could you give an example, pls.

Comment: To cite that page: "Today, W3Schools has largely resolved these issues and addressed the majority of the undersigned developers' concerns. For many beginners, W3Schools has structured tutorials and playgrounds that offer a decent learning experience." Of course, w3schools is not the page you should stay on, but it serves as a well-written *introduction*

Comment: still - it still includes enough bad practice / errors to avoid, and maybe, for me the best way I learnt PHP was just read PHP documentation, it's well written and pretty full.. and offically made by PHP

Comment: @this He’s pointing to the Ajax intro. And you have to admit, if someone knows nothing about Ajax, w3schools is not a bad starting point

Comment: @itcher I'll take your word for it :) I got shown by a friend how to, so full interactive tutorial for me haha got lucky :)